# How to format output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, formatting

The script code is for Fibonacci Series. The problem is the output doesn't look good for the eyes. The output is something like this `0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,5...`. What I want is to format this output and add space after the comma. Is it possible?

```
<div class="outer">
        <div class="container">
           <button onclick="fibonacci_series(90)">Click To Display Fibonacci Series up to 90</button>
           <p id="demo"> </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
         var fibonacci_series = function (n) {
            if (n == 1) {
                var loop = [0, 1];
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = loop;
                return loop
            }
            else {
                var s = fibonacci_series(n - 1);
                s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = s;
                return s    
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be done with the `Array.join(str)` method, which connects the items in the array to a specific character.

> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = s.join(", ");

Below is the result of adding the join method to one line of your code.

```html
<div class="outer">
        <div class="container">
           <button onclick="fibonacci_series(90)">Click To Display Fibonacci Series up to 90</button>
           <p id="demo"> </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
         var fibonacci_series = function (n) {
            if (n == 1) {
                var loop = [0, 1];
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = loop;
                return loop
            }
            else {
                var s = fibonacci_series(n - 1);
                s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = s.join(", ");
                return s    
            }
        };
    </script>
```

> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = s.map(n =>
> `<li>${n}</li>`).join("\n");

Below is an example of modifying the code on the same line, and wrapping the li element around the numbers to make it much easier to see.

```html
<div class="outer">
        <div class="container">
           <button onclick="fibonacci_series(90)">Click To Display Fibonacci Series up to 90</button>
           <p id="demo"> </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
         var fibonacci_series = function (n) {
            if (n == 1) {
                var loop = [0, 1];
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = loop;
                return loop
            }
            else {
                var s = fibonacci_series(n - 1);
                s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = s.map(n => `<li>${n}</li>`).join("\n");
                return s    
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: I have searched about the `.join(' ');` I just didnt know where to put it. But wrapping them in a list is a much better choice. Thanks a lot!.